# Por quê minha condição não está me dando o resultado esperado?

Tags: php, array, for, condição

Estou realizando uma quebra de linhas sem usar a função `wordwrap()`.

Receberei uma string com o texto, e um int com o comprimento de caracteres permitido por linhas como parâmetro. Terei que cortar essa string, depois inserí-la num vetor já cortada. As condições para corte são:

1. Se uma palavra não couber na linha e o comprimento dela for menor que o limite de caracteres, ela não deve ser cortada, e sim jogada para a próxima linha.
2. Se a palavra for maior que o limite de caracteres por linha, corte a palavra e continue a imprimi-la na linha seguinte.

Eu acho que provavelmente o erro esteja nas condições porém não estou conseguindo identificá-lo, alguma ajuda?

Ao imprimir o vetor, eu recebo:

> Array(0)=>'Se vi mais'
>   Array(1)=>'longe foi'
>   Array(2)=>'por estar'
>   Array(3)=>'de pé'
>   Array(4)=>'sobre'
>   Array(5)=>'ombros de'
>   Array(6)=>'gigantes'

Porém, preciso imprimir:

> Array(0)=>'Se vi mais'
>   Array(1)=>'longe foi'
>   Array(2)=>'por estar de'
>   Array(3)=>'pé sobre'
>   Array(4)=>'ombros de'
>   Array(5)=>'gigantes'

Segue o código que desenvolvi abaixo:

```
  class Resolution implements TextWrapInterface {

  public function textWrap(string $text,int $length):array {
//local variables
$words=explode(" ",$text); //separate the text into words
$arr=array();              //array used for return
$string=" ";
$limit=$length; //limit of characters per line
$line=0;//array line

for($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++){
    $string = $words[$i]." ";
   if((strlen($words[$i])>$length)){
    //cut the world and print the remaining letters on the next line
    $this->cutWord($arr,$words[$i],$limit,$length,$line);  
  }else
   if($limit>=strlen($string)){    
        //add the word in array line
        $arr[$line]=(array_key_exists($line,$arr))? 
    $arr[$line].$string:$string;
        //subtract the limit with the quantity of characters
        $limit-=strlen($string);
    }else 
        if($limit<strlen($string)){

            //line++ for inserting the string on a next index
            $line++;
            $limit=$length;
            //add the word on array line
            $arr[$line]=$string;
            //subtract the limit with the quantity of characters
            $limit-=strlen($string);
        }
   }

    return $arr;
     print_r($arr);

   }

   //and then I've got a cutWord function
  private function cutWord(&$array,$word,&$limit,$length,$index){

 for($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++){ 

//verify if the index doesn't have any words in
 if(($limit!=$length)&&($i==0)){
  $index++; // jump an array line
  $limit=$length; //limit receives starting value
 }
//verify if the limit is > 0
 if($limit<=0) {
$index++;
$limit=$length; //limit receives starting value
 }
//add the letter in the array index concatenating with the previous
$array[$index]=(array_key_exists($index,$array))? 
$array[$index].$word[$i]:$word[$i];
$limit--;
}
    $array[$index]=$array[$index]." ";
}
```

Comment: Qual é o valor que estás passando para `length`?

Comment: Estou passando 12.

Comment: Passa 13 então. 12 corta a string que deveria ser o resultado esperado em `Array(2)` (- Por estar de -)